# I want find min element of object by attribute in a list of objects in Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, object, attributes

I want find min element of object (by `days` attribute) in a list of objects in Python, I have this code so far:

```py
from operator import attrgetter
    
lists = json.loads("[" + data + "]")
print(lists)
maintenance_cycle = min(lists,key=lambda r: r.days)
```

- Console output:

```py
[{'type': 'runtime', 'days': 1}]
```

- Error:

```py
'dict' object has no attribute 'days'
```

Comment: How about using `min(lists, key=lambda r: r['days'])` or perhaps `min(lists, key=lambda r: r.get('days'))` .

Comment: @GhostOps, are you sure? your first suggestion sounded good. `maintenance_cycle = min(lists,key=lambda r: r['days'])`

Comment: @StéphaneGRILLON i know its not, now i lost time to edit that comment, so let me delete the comment, and JonSG got what you want

Comment: @StéphaneGRILLON Did you want a solution that specifically uses the `operator` module?

Comment: @GhostOps if you put in an answer as it looks like you might have had what was needed from the start, I will delete my comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing dictionary keys is not like accessing class methods

Try this code

```py
maintenance_cycle = min(lists, key=lambda r: r['days'])
```

Or

```py
maintenance_cycle = min(lists, key=lambda r: r.get('days'))
```

Instead of

```py
maintenance_cycle = min(lists,key=lambda r: r.days)
```

And tell me if its not working...

Comment: My code need this: `min(recurrences, key=lambda r: r['days'])['days']` but your answer helped me. thank you

Comment: @Stéphane GRILLON  whats recurrences tho?

Comment: sorry, `lists` in this sample. `min(lists, key=lambda r: r['days'])['days']`